# JSForce Username and password authentication strategy

Tags: authentication, node.js, jsforce

I'm using the username, password + authcode strategy in a node app to connect to salesforce.

I've got a module to connect, and another to login to salesforce.  Connect opens the connection and makes the conn variable available, login actually does the logging in.

Initially I had all routes calling conn and login, but logging in every single time slows the app and makes a lot of API calls. I noticed in the documentation it says to store the accessToken and loginUrl after calling login to use them on future connections, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best strategy for making use of the accessToken and loginUrl.

If I save and hardcode the accessToken and loginUrl, and stop calling login, it works for a while, but eventually they expire and things stop working.

I've seen suggestions for calling login if a query fails, but that seems like I'd have to write a lot of code to handle retries for every single function that uses conn - so it feels like that isn't the best way.

Is there a "right way" to handle this process? I can't figure out how to check if they accessToken is still valid without making an API call, at which point I might as well just login every time since it's going to consume resources every time it checks anyway.

Ideas?

*Update:
This is what I'm using and it works, though probably not the best implementation.

```
let accessToken = 'MadeUpTokenThatWontWorkTheFirstTime'
let instanceUrl = 'https://YOURINSTANCE.salesforce.com'
let sfConnection
module.exports.conn = async (req, res, next) => {
  let settings = {}
  settings.instanceUrl = _get(sfConnection, 'instanceUrl', instanceUrl)
  settings.accessToken = _get(sfConnection, 'accessToken', accessToken)

  sfConnection = new jsforce.Connection({ loginUrl: process.env.SF_LOGINURL, instanceUrl: settings.instanceUrl, accessToken: settings.accessToken })
  // Try to describe an object to see if the credentials work
  await sfConnection.describe(process.env.A_SF_OBJECT)
    .catch( async function() {
      // Credentials didnt work, getting new ones! Make sure to use your password + security code
      return sfConnection = await sfConnection.login(process.env.SF_USERNAME, process.env.SF_PASSWORDAndCODE)
        .then(() => {
          return sfConnection
        })
    })
  //Attach to req so it's available
  req.conn = sfConnection
  // return sfConnection
  next()
}
```

Comment: I know this question is old but would you be willing to share the code you were using that works for a while but eventually fails. Or better yet if you found an answer would you be willing to share.

Comment: @JosephU. I've added what works for me to the original. If you find a better way, let me know!

Comment: @McB You can answer your own question!

Comment: @DavidReed I got it working... but I'm pretty confident it isn't the *best* way to do it. Feels (and looks) very messy!

Comment: Note, calling `connection.describe` can incur large networking overheads for some Salesforce objects. Instead, you might try calling `connection.identity()` which in my tests incurs less of a bandwidth and time cost.